# What is this error in a Makefile?

Tags: windows, makefile, windows-7, cygwin, 32-bit

Using 'make' from the ARM DS-5 5.22 release on Cygwin, I am processing a makefile containing the lines:

```
if [[ ! -d "$(OBJ_DIR)" ]]; \
    then $(MD) "$(OBJ_DIR)"; fi
```

This evaluates to:

```
if [[ ! -d "../../output/obj" ]]; \
    then mkdir -p "../../output/obj"; fi
```

When making, I get an error:

```
make -C ./src/modules
make[1]: Entering directory `C:/Users/me/Documents/proj/src/modules'
if [[ ! -d "../../output/obj" ]]; \
        then mkdir -p "../../output/obj"; fi
! was unexpected at this time.
make[1]: *** [setenv] Error 255
make[1]: Leaving directory `C:/Users/me/Documents/proj/src/modules'
make: *** [drivers] Error 2
```

When explicitly running the `mkdir` command from the command line, it works as expected and the `output/obj` directory is created with no problems.

This script works fine on other computers.

**What does the `! was unexpected at this time.` error mean, and how to fix that?**

**UPDATE:** The `make` command is invoked from the following shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

export PATH='./:/usr/bin/:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/ARMCompiler6.6/bin/'
export ARM_PRODUCT_PATH='c:/DS-5_v5.22/sw/mappings'
export USEARMCOMPILER6=1
export DS5VER=DS-5_5.22

/cygdrive/c/DS-5_v5.22/bin/make "$@"
```

Comment: Do you override the `SHELL` variable in the makefile?   Try running `bin/sh` to get into sh, and then `if [[ ! -d "../../output/obj" ]]; then mkdir -p "../../output/obj"; fi` from that shell on the build machine.

Comment: @John - thanks. I do not override the SHELL variable, AFAIK. I updated the question with the calling shell script. When I run the whole `if` command from CLI, it seems to work fine.

Comment: When you say you run from the cli, are you in a bash shell or /bin/sh?  (Type `echo $0` to be sure).   Make defaults to whatever is in /bin/sh.  In fact, you can add the `echo $$0` recipe in your rule to be sure which shell make is running.   Your problem _sounds_ like your shell is not liking the syntax.  It could also be that you have a hidden character (try retyping...).

Comment: I'll check once I have access to that system, but isn't `make` running in the context of the invoking script (which means `/bin/bash`)?

Comment: no -- it defaults to using `bin/sh` (see [choosing the shell](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Choosing-the-Shell.html))

Comment: From CLI, `echo $0` gives `-bash`. From the makefile rule, the `echo` command then evaluates as the CMD command, hence returning `$0` (when `echo $$0`) or `ECHO is off` (when `echo $0`).

However, echoing `echo ${SHELL}` in the makefile returns `sh.exe`.

Comment: @John - Another observation - as you suggested, I entered `sh.exe` and used the offending `if` command from CLI and it works fine, just like when doing so from `bash`.

Comment: Ahh, so your if statement is being interpreted as a CMD command as well, and CMD doesn't understand the `!` (I just tried it on a dos prompt, and got the behavior you're describing).   You can try setting `SHELL:= /bin/bash` or `SHELL:=/bin/sh` at the top of your makefile (note that `sh.exe` is not the same thing as `/bin/sh`...)

Comment: The issue if [[  operator which isn't supported by /bin/sh. You can simply use simple form [ here.   Shorter form could be:   [ -d "$(OBJ_DIR)" ] || $(MD) "$(OBJ_DIR)"

Comment: @John - it may be so... but the same script works on 2 other machines running Cygwin on Win7 32 & 64.

Comment: @levif -- the problem is that the ! is not supported by `cmd` (i.e. dos shell), which also doesn't understand the `-d`, etc...  so @ysap would need to force the machine to use a linux shell to execute the recipes.

Comment: @ysap, I can't speak as to why that particular version is defaulting to using a dos shell to execute the recipes, but I think you will need to force it to use a linux shell, otherwise that won't be your only problem...   You'll likely have to look at the man pages for the particular version of make you're using to get it to do that.